# How to check if instance implements CollectionType?

Tags: swift

I'm defining a function that prints out an instance of `Any`. If it is an `NSArray` or a `CollectionType` it prints out how many items it has and a maximum of 10 of its items:

```
static func prettyPrint(any: Any) -> String {
    switch any {
    case is NSArray:
        let array = any as! NSArray
        var result: String = "\(array.count) items ["
        for i in 0 ..< array.count {
            if (i > 0) {
                result += ", "
            }
            result += "\(array[i])"
            if (i > 10) {
                result += ", ..."
                break;
            }
        }
        result += "]"
        return result

    default:
        assertionFailure("No pretty print defined for \(any.dynamicType)")
        return ""
    }
}
```

I want to add a case clause for any `CollectionType`, but I can't because it is a type that involves generics. The compiler message is:  `Protocol 'CollectionType' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`
I just need to iterate and the `count` property to create the print string, I don't care about the type of the elements the collection contains.

How can I check for `CollectionType<?>`?

Comment: Interestingly enough the Swift Types are bridged with the Objective-C Types and will work in these cases. I tried your function with a [String] and it worked. Is there a type that is not working so well?

Comment: @AdamCampbell indeed it works, so I guess check for an NSArray is enough for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Mirror` - base it on something like this...

```
func prettyPrint(any: Any) -> String {
    var result = ""
    let m = Mirror(reflecting: any)
    switch m.displayStyle {
    case .Some(.Collection):
        result = "Collection, \(m.children.count) elements"
    case .Some(.Tuple):
        result = "Tuple, \(m.children.count) elements"
    case .Some(.Dictionary):
        result = "Dictionary, \(m.children.count) elements"
    case .Some(.Set):
        result = "Set, \(m.children.count) elements"
    default: // Others are .Struct, .Class, .Enum, .Optional & nil
        result = "\(m.displayStyle)"
    }

    return result
}

prettyPrint([1, 2, 3]) // "Collection, 3 elements"
prettyPrint(NSArray(array:[1, 2, 3])) // "Collection, 3 elements"
prettyPrint(Set<String>()) // "Set, 0 elements"
prettyPrint([1:2, 3:4]) // "Dictionary, 2 elements"
prettyPrint((1, 2, 3)) // "Tuple, 3 elements"
prettyPrint(3) // "nil"
prettyPrint("3") // "nil"
```

Check out http://appventure.me/2015/10/24/swift-reflection-api-what-you-can-do/

Comment: I didn't know about the 'Mirror' struct, I've been enlightened!